# Creating temporary table in SQL Server 2008 from VBScript

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript, temp-tables

I am trying to query a SQL Server 2008 instance from VBScript.
I know my connection is working because when I use a simple query such as the one below it works fine.

```
sfQuery2 = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [DB].[schema].[table]"
```

The one thing I am unsure about is the user that I am connected as has read only rights. Not sure if the userid will be able to create temp tables if they are read only. I did run the same query from SQL Server with this user and the query worked. But when I try to run this with the same user from vbscript when I try to read the record set the error I get is.....

> ADODB.Recordset: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

```
sfQuery2 = "CREATE TABLE #Temp1  ([LOGNAME] [nvarchar](20) NULL,    [MESSAGE_TYPE] [int] NULL,  [COMPONENT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    [LOGTIME] [nvarchar](17) NOT NULL,  [SUB_SYSTEM] [nvarchar](40) NULL,   [STACK_ID] [nvarchar](120) NULL,    [SUBSTACK_ID] [int] NULL,   [MESSAGE] [nvarchar](1800) NULL,    [DETAIL] [nvarchar](1800) NULL )  INSERT INTO #Temp1 SELECT DISTINCT [LOGNAME], [MESSAGE_TYPE],                 [COMPONENT], LOGTIME,               [SUB_SYSTEM], [STACK_ID],               [SUBSTACK_ID], [MESSAGE],               [DETAIL]                FROM [DB].[schema].[table]  WHERE cast(LEFT(LOGTIME,8) as date) = cast(getdate() -1 as date)    AND [MESSAGE] LIKE '%Exporter->Archive' CREATE TABLE #Temp2  ([LOGNAME] [nvarchar](20) NULL,    [MESSAGE_TYPE] [int] NULL,  [COMPONENT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    [LOGTIME] [nvarchar](17) NOT NULL,  [SUB_SYSTEM] [nvarchar](40) NULL,   [STACK_ID] [nvarchar](120) NULL,    [SUBSTACK_ID] [int] NULL,   [MESSAGE] [nvarchar](1800) NULL,    [DETAIL] [nvarchar](1800) NULL )  INSERT INTO #Temp2 SELECT DISTINCT [LOGNAME], [MESSAGE_TYPE],                 [COMPONENT],cast(LEFT(LOGTIME,8) as date) AS YesterdayDate,                 [SUB_SYSTEM], [STACK_ID],               [SUBSTACK_ID], [MESSAGE],               [DETAIL]                FROM [DB].[schema].[table]  WHERE cast(LEFT(LOGTIME,8) as date) = cast(getdate() -1 as date)    AND [DETAIL] LIKE 'USER:%' SELECT * FROM (  SELECT RIGHT(b.DETAIL, 7) AS AXAID, cast(LEFT(a.LOGTIME,8) as date) AS [DATE], b.STACK_ID,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by b.STACK_ID ORDER BY a.LOGTIME DESC) rn   FROM #Temp1 AS a    INNER JOIN #Temp2 AS b  ON a.STACK_ID = b.STACK_ID  WHERE a.[MESSAGE] LIKE '%Exporter->Archive'     ) a WHERE rn = 1 "
oSfRs.Open sfQuery2, oSfCn

if osfrs.BOF then 
Debug "There are NO results"
else
Debug "There is data in the Record Set"
end if
```

I am not sure if it is a syntax error with my SQL or if there it possibly because the rights of the user. Any help would be appreciate. 
Please let me know if more information is needed.

---

For those struggling to read the SQL here is a formatted version

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Temp1  (
    [LOGNAME] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [MESSAGE_TYPE] [int] NULL,  
    [COMPONENT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    
    [LOGTIME] [nvarchar](17) NOT NULL,  
    [SUB_SYSTEM] [nvarchar](40) NULL,   
    [STACK_ID] [nvarchar](120) NULL,    
    [SUBSTACK_ID] [int] NULL,   
    [MESSAGE] [nvarchar](1800) NULL,    
    [DETAIL] [nvarchar](1800) NULL 
)  

INSERT INTO #Temp1 
SELECT DISTINCT [LOGNAME], [MESSAGE_TYPE], [COMPONENT], LOGTIME, [SUB_SYSTEM]
, [STACK_ID], [SUBSTACK_ID], [MESSAGE], [DETAIL]
FROM [DB].[schema].[table]  
WHERE cast(LEFT(LOGTIME,8) as date) = cast(getdate() -1 as date)    
AND [MESSAGE] LIKE '%Exporter->Archive' 

CREATE TABLE #Temp2  (
    [LOGNAME] [nvarchar](20) NULL,    
    [MESSAGE_TYPE] [int] NULL,  
    [COMPONENT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    
    [LOGTIME] [nvarchar](17) NOT NULL,  
    [SUB_SYSTEM] [nvarchar](40) NULL,   
    [STACK_ID] [nvarchar](120) NULL,    
    [SUBSTACK_ID] [int] NULL,   
    [MESSAGE] [nvarchar](1800) NULL,    
    [DETAIL] [nvarchar](1800) NULL 
)  

INSERT INTO #Temp2 SELECT DISTINCT [LOGNAME], [MESSAGE_TYPE], [COMPONENT]
, cast(LEFT(LOGTIME,8) as date) AS YesterdayDate
, [SUB_SYSTEM], [STACK_ID], [SUBSTACK_ID], [MESSAGE], [DETAIL]
FROM [DB].[schema].[table]  
WHERE cast(LEFT(LOGTIME,8) as date) = cast(getdate() -1 as date)    
AND [DETAIL] LIKE 'USER:%' 

SELECT * 
FROM (  
    SELECT RIGHT(b.DETAIL, 7) AS AXAID, cast(LEFT(a.LOGTIME,8) as date) AS [DATE]
    , b.STACK_ID,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by b.STACK_ID ORDER BY a.LOGTIME DESC) rn   
    FROM #Temp1 AS a    
    INNER JOIN #Temp2 AS b  ON a.STACK_ID = b.STACK_ID  
    WHERE a.[MESSAGE] LIKE '%Exporter->Archive'     
) a WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Do you really write that much sql directly in your application on a single line? It is impossible to decipher that. The error message is pretty clear here. It has nothing to do with sql permissions, it has to do with your objects. My guess is you never open your database connection.

Comment: You should really package this SQL into a Stored Procedure, managing it like this will be a nightmare.

Comment: The issue is going to be the lack of `SET NOCOUNT ON;` so all the `INSERT` statements will be producing empty closed recordsets. At the moment without `SET NOCOUNT ON;` you will have to keep calling `Set oSfRs = oSfRs.NextRecordset` until you find the recordset that corresponds to the `SELECT` executation in your SQL.

Comment: Lankmart, you are correct it is a duplicate question. Using the SET NOCOUNT ON clause resolved my issues. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @hfrog713 glad it helped, just bear in mind that you would still be better placing that SQL into a Stored Procedure and calling that instead, it's far easier to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by comment by Lankymart. 
The resolution was to add SET NOCOUNT ON to the beginning of my query.